# finding the average centralities on certain condition in R

Tags: r

Hi I am trying to find a solution to a problem that is I have a `data.frame`, which consist of a network of users edits on certain articles. The `data.frame` looks like this:

```
faID   uID1   uID2
1       a1     a2
1       a1     a3
1       a2     a3
2       a3     b1
2       a3     b2
2       b1     b2
3       a1     b1
3       b1     b2
3       b3     b1
```

What I want is to find the centrality score of the users on the article basis, i.e. compute centralities score for `article 1` then compute centrality score for `article 2` and so on. And then find the average of these centralities scores and display then with `article id` like this:

```
faID     avg.cent
1         0.000000    (certain value)
2          0.00000
3          0.0000
```

I hope I have explained it well. Your response will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: to find the average centralities score on article basis like the above proposed output. i.e to find the centrality score of  all the user upto that article say article 1(faID1) and then find the average of that and diplayed it with article(like above).

Comment: @user3841811 I edited your post to reformat your code for better readability, but I can't tell if certain lines beginning with a `#` are supposed to be R comments or emphasized text (in StackOverflow markdown). If these lines are not intended to be R comments please remove the `#`s.

Comment: @user3841811 Can you provide `w1`?

Comment: @Hack-R w1 is the aboave dataframe consist of "faID","uID1" and "uID2"

Comment: any help with the code?